# How to concatenate dataframes without overwriting column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, concatenation

I am trying to create a list of DataFrames in a for loop, and then concatenate them outside of the for loop and write to excel. I have gotten the code to be close, but for some reason the column created inside the for loop ends up being the final value rather each individual value as it loops through. I am sure this is extremely simple and I'm just missing something easy but cannot seem to figure it out tonight. Here is some dummy code to illustrate and help with problem solving. At the end, I'd like an excel output with wks 1 - 9. However, in my actual output all values in the wk column are equal to 9.

```
import pandas as pd
sample = []
area = pd.Series({'California':423967, 'Texas':695662})
pop = pd.Series({'California':38332521, 'Texas':26448193})

data = pd.DataFrame({'area':area, 'pop':pop})
print(data)

for i in range(10):
    data['wk'] = i
    sample.append(data)
    print(data)

res = pd.concat(sample)
res.to_excel("Concatenating DataFrames.xlsx", index=False)
```

Comment: data['wk'] is a column, not an element  but you are trying to assign it one value, In this case, pandas will populate all the rows of the column with the same value.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow exactly. I know it is a column. However, I thought by writing it to a list of DataFrames and then concatenating them it would retain it's value. For example, when I print(data) it shows the first DataFrame with week 1, the second with week 2, etc. How do I keep those values when finally concatenating the list of DataFrames together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies here that when you append the data to list it does not create the separate memory for it rather they all refer to the same memory that's why after last updation in the loop it becomes 9  or final value.

just replace

```
sample.append(data)
```

with

```
sample.append(data.copy())
```

.copy() will enforce pandas to create new memory for each df in loop

Comment: I'm not a programmer by trade, but any best practices for learning about memory and memory allocation? I mistakenly assumed it would write the dataframe to the list each time, thus retaining whatever week value that dataframe had. Obviously, I was wrong, but would appreciate any thoughts or advice to better understand why it does this and understanding memory/memory allocation.

Answer (score 0):

Making multiple dataframes in a loop and concatenating them is very inefficient.  It's better to do the iteration on lists or dictionaries, then create a single dataframe after the loop.  Below, I have converted your series back to dictionaries for this purpose.  Notice that the dictionaries have to be copied in each iteration of the loop so that the loop does not keep mutating the original dictionaries.

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
from copy import deepcopy

area = pd.Series({'California':423967, 'Texas':695662})
pop = pd.Series({'California':38332521, 'Texas':26448193})
area_d = area.to_dict()
pop_d = pop.to_dict()

sample = []
for i in range(10):
    area_copy = deepcopy(area_d)
    pop_copy = deepcopy(pop_d)
    area_copy['wk'] = i
    pop_copy['wk'] = i
    sample += [area_copy, pop_copy]
df = pd.DataFrame(sample)
df.to_excel("result.xlsx", index = False)
```

Comment: I see this works when the area and pop are static. In my real life scenario, the underlying data changes. For instance, it aggregates sales by week one and calculates an average and rank. Then it loops through a second time, pulling in data from week 1-2, and repeats the process, etc through a number of weeks. Would this scenario work to do that? I assume not, because area and pop in this example would change with each for loop. That is why  I created a list of dataframes to concatenate outside of the loop, but I'd be happy to hear more memory efficient ways as I'm still learning.

Comment: @ShawnSchreier I am fairly certain it would work.  Provide an example that captures your workflow more realistically, and we can look at it.